# Cannot find module @google-cloud/firestore on AppEngine using node.js standard environment

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have deployed a cron on **AppEngine** using **node.js standard environment** in order to update regularly my Firestore database.

Following [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-nodejs-libraries), linking to [this list](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/libraries) of available npm modules, I should be able to use **@google-cloud/firestore**, but after:

`npm i --save @google-cloud/firestore`

I get the following error:

`Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/firestore'`

At the line:

```
var firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
```

My package.json is the same as the Hello World sample:

```
{
  "name": "appengine-hello-world",
  "description": "Simple Hello World Node.js sample for Google App Engine Standard Environment.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.x.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "lint": "repo-tools lint",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "system-test": "repo-tools test app",
    "test": "npm run system-test",
    "e2e-test": "repo-tools test deploy"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.14.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/nodejs-repo-tools": "^2.3.0",
    "semistandard": "^12.0.1"
  },
  "cloud-repo-tools": {
    "test": {
      "app": {
        "msg": "Hello, world!"
      }
    },
    "requiresKeyFile": true,
    "requiresProjectId": true
  }
}
```

And finally I deploy with:

```
gcloud app deploy --version=v8 --promote
```

How am I supposed to use firestore in my cron ?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain how you installed the module, as well as the contents of your package.json.

Comment: @DougStevenson done

Comment: I've just encountered with the same error message.Solved just by :
npm *install* --save @google-cloud/firestore

Sorry, but is it a typo in your command: 'i' instead of 'install' 
or it is an abbreviation which I don't know?

Answer (score 11):

There seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2830#issuecomment-399189137) with installing `@grpc`. If your `@grpc` was corrupted by a previous attempts to install it, it will likely keep failing if you just keep trying to install. Doing `npm install @google-cloud/firestore` will also try to install grpc, so the whole thing won't successfully complete if grpc is corrupted.

**Try deleting your entire `nodes_modules` folder and install your packages from scratch.**

As to why the grpc gets corrupted in the first place, I'm not too sure. Any clean install from my Windows Shell Command (cmd.exe) gave me the same problem over and over.

However, I was able to successfully install everything on an Ubuntu virtual machine using Ubuntu's linux terminal. Later I realized the same thing was possible even on a Windows OS using Windows' Linux Subsystem instead of Shell Command ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cvrqmq9A3tA) is a video that shows how to setup an Ubuntu terminal for Windows). So the Shell Command seems to be the issue. For some reason that I haven't looked into yet, it's not working well with some `@google-cloud/*` packages.

That being said, it might also be possible to correctly install those packages on Windows using something like [Cmder](http://cmder.net/) or anything else than the Shell Command (I can't confirm, I haven't tried).

Comment: Thank you for this. I ended up using powershell and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

delete node_module and run `npm install`. it might run without error. I once was getting error while using firebase-admin with express. removing node_module and re-installing all packages again worked for me